# Auto layout how to hide 1 view in a view with 3 equal width views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Currently I have 3 views inside 1 view (which is pinned to leading edge and trailing edge of superview).

The 3 views look like this currently:

[image: 3 views with equal widths]

However, in some cases, I wish to hide the indigo view, but still keep the last 2 the same widths like so:
[image: 2 views with equal widths with indigo view hiding]

How can I achieve this with autolayout? Or how can I achieve this using IBOutlets for constraints?

Comment: Have you tried creating an IBOutlet and then using the .hidden property?

Comment: @MatthewBradshaw what would the IBOutlet be connected to?

Comment: Connect the view you want to manipulate programmatically to an IBOutlet by control dragging into the assistant editor.  Then manipulate that outlet.  The .hidden property is a boolean.  Check out this tutorial https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html

Comment: Have you tried using `UIStackView`?

Comment: @tktsubota I'm supporting iOS 8 as well so that's not an option unfortunately. Stackview would make it so much easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If the deployment target is iOS9 or later**, it is recommended to use `UIStackView` as the enclosing view. Setting `isHidden` to `true` on any view arranged in the `UIStackView` will not only make the view hidden, but also will the stack view re-organize all the non-hidden views to fill up the space that was taken by the hidden views. This behavior could be tuned by adjusting `distribution` on `UIStackView`.

---

Tj3n's answer works, but it has a drawback that you have to use magic numbers in your code and set constraint properties both in code and IB.

IMHO, a better solution would be setting up all the constraints in IB with different priorities and activating/deactivating them in code. Try this:

1. Set the leading/trailing constraints as you did before.
2. Set equal width constraints for all three views with priority `high`.
3. Set 0 width constraints for all three views with priority `required`, but leave them deactivated in IB. And connect them to `IBOutlet`s in code just as connecting views.
4. Activate any of the 0 width constraints to collapse the view you want, and later deactivate them to expand.

Note that just with 1 and 2 in place, you can achieve the equal-width view layout. And with 3 and 4, you can collapse/expand any of the views selectively.

Comment: how do i activate a constraint?

Comment: `NSLayoutConstraint` has boolean property `isActive`

Comment: got it. are the 0 width constraints automatically deactivated when i add them in IB?

Comment: No they are activated by default. There is a checkbox named `installed` in the inspector. It just means activated, uncheck it to make the constraint deactivated. The name is misleading.

Comment: This is lovely. The only problem is that you can't toggle this in IB or (in my case) see it there.

Comment: Hi @Alper, if you are supporting iOS 9 or later, `UIStackView` is much easier to use and recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty easy, you can create equal width constraint A for the 3 view, set its priority is 998, then create another single width constraint B1, B2, B3 for them, set priority is 997, if you want to hide any of the 3 view, set B constraint's constant to 0, and up its priority to 999, then call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded`, the view will hide and others will scale

The test constraint is the width constraint of the gray view:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by single width constraint?

Comment: mean u click on that, press the Pin button below, then check on `width`, then set its priority to 997, u must make property for it to change priority later in code though

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the indigo view which can be hidden, you should solve your problem by adding this constraints :

Indigo view : leading to superview + trailing to purpleView + width constraint

Purple view : same width as grayView

Gray View : leading to purpleView + trailing to superview

It should looks like this :

[image: Constraints]

[image: View]

And if you change the width property of your indigoView, all should follow correctly.

Hope that help you.

Comment: But there is no specified width constraint for the indigo view, so how would I programmatically hide it?

Comment: You just have to link your constraint as an IBOutlet, and set yourConstraint.constant at 0 and your indigoView.frame.size.width at 0 too. By this way, by setting your indigoView width, you will have the others view which use the entire restant width.