# Equal Width Constraints with one or more views' width equal to zero

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have 4 views
which are having equal width constraints
now I want to make one's width to zero
while other views resize (width-wise) themselves to fill its place
how do I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto layout how to hide 1 view in a view with 3 equal width views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364555/auto-layout-how-to-hide-1-view-in-a-view-with-3-equal-width-views)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out UIStackView. UIStackView does exactly what you need. But be aware that UIStackView is available only in iOS 9 and higher.

If you must support lower iOS than 9.0 then you should manually change constraints when one of the views is removed or resized.
To do this manually:

1. You should remove 'equal width' constraints from your views
2. Add new constraints to your views
3. Call layoutIfNeeded() method to apply constraints

You can create new constraints like this:

```
let view1Cnst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view2, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1.0)
view1.addConstraint(view1Cnst)
```

I hope you can use UIStackView because it is easier approach.