# How we can increase width of two button when we remove third button from view

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, ios-autolayout

I have view with three button with equal size. Each button take 1/3 part portion of view.

Like this image:

[image]

If I remove/hide one button then two button width should increase equally and take 1/2 portion of view. if I remove two button then one button size should be equal size of view.

My question is, how it's possible using the Autolayout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto layout how to hide 1 view in a view with 3 equal width views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364555/auto-layout-how-to-hide-1-view-in-a-view-with-3-equal-width-views)

Comment: Do you wish to remove the button completely or just hide and unhide it?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as a duplicate because unlike the linked question this one doesn't specify it has to be with AutoLayout, and `UIStackView` is not mentioned in the answers of that other question.

Answer (score 6):

Best option is using stackView. StackView gives lots of flexibility in adding or removing items. If you wish to use only auto layouts, you can achieve it by connect it's width constraints as IBOutlet and change the values programatically.

Comment: Yes StackView gives the more flexible and easy to create like this. but How we can perform only using the constant. Please give any suggestion tutorials or links.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do that is to use UISTACKVIEW.Place a stackview and add 3 buttons.You can give proper layout constraints to the stack view as you need

click on stack view-- select attribute inspector
change distribution--fill equally
spacing--0

Then after that if you hide any button,other buttons will be automatically adjusted in width

Answer (score 0):

Other Possible sol to this problem is Adding or removing constraints during runtime is a heavyweight operation that can affect performance. However, there is a simpler alternative.

For the view you wish to hide, set up a width constraint. Constrain the other views with a leading horizontal gap to that view.

To hide, update the .constant of the width constraint to 0.f. The other views will automatically move left to assume position. and for equal width pervoid multiplier to width..

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. `UIStackView` which was made exactly for this.
2. `UICollectionView` similar to `UIStackView` in a certain way, but not really meant for this. However, it does the job nicely and it's easy to implement. Sometimes easier than `UIStackView`.
3. `NSLayoutConstraint` by using multiple constraints with different priority so that you can activate/deactivate them as needed and get the desired result. This approach is a bit more complex by it gives you the highest degree of control and flexibility over the views in your hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you are looking for is, like others have already mentioned, to use a `UIStackView`.

When the `isHidden` property of a `UIView` inside a stack view is set to true, that stack view will hide the view and take care of the layout, so you will only need to set the correct constraints for your stack view.