# how to remove button with equalwidths dynamically

Tags: button, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

[image]

I have three buttons with equal widths in storyboard , now i want to remove one button dynamically , so that other two should fit equally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364555/auto-layout-how-to-hide-1-view-in-a-view-with-3-equal-width-views

Comment: @MadhuriJujama  thnx a lot . it's really helped me